# @Named bean not injected into @Stateless bean

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, cdi

I have a @Stateless bean in an EJB module

```
@Stateless 
public class Foo {
    @Inject Bar bar;

    public void helloFromBar() { return bar.hello(); }
}
```

I have a @Named bean in the same EJB module

```
@Named @ApplicationScoped
public class Bar {
    public String hello () { return "hello"; }
}
```

Bar#hello is called from a CDI bean in a web module.

```
@Named @ViewScoped
public class ViewBean {

    @EJB Foo foo;

    public String callFoo() { return foo.helloFromBar(); }

}
```

For some reason Bar is not injected into Foo - it is always a null reference.  I would expect that this would work.

Comment: Do you have the constructor of Bar annotated with @Inject?

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan Why would that matter?

Comment: @anger Does the EJB module contain `META-INF/beans.xml`?

Comment: @bkail AFAIK, user defined class should have an injectable constructor? Is that not needed?

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan No, they're not needed. Injectable constructors are just an alternative to `@Inject` fields. I believe the major advantage is the ability to use `final` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @bkail's comment, I was missing META-INF/beans.xml.